# Solve the differential equation and initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My Professor is asking us to solve the following differential equation and initial value problem but does not provide any further instructions. Could someone please help me get started?

1.) $D^3(D+5)(D+3)^2(D^2+16)y = 0$

and

2.)$2x e^y \mathrm{d}x+(x^2e^y+y \cos y)\mathrm{d}y = 0$

Comment: Multiplication, i'll make the change

Comment: Hint for $2.$, it is an Exact Equation. The first one could not me more straightforward.

Comment: Is solving a differential equation the same as providing a general solution for it?

Comment: Please, stop writing latex with only $\$^y\$$, the dollar notation is meant to be used for a whole equation. Well, sorry, it's not especially after you, but it's a bad habit that seems to spread on MSE.

Comment: @user100707: Yes, you can solve these, but do not have initial conditions, thus will have unknown constants floating about.

Comment: @arbautjc : sorry I don't understand the comment, how should one write in-line math? I always use the dollar sign (isn't it from pure TeX? ).

Comment: @SergioParreiras Look at my edit, and you'll see what I mean ;-) The dollar sign is fine, but there is only one (or a pair of course if not inline) at the beginning and one at the end of the equation. No need to put dollars everywhere, just to put something "in exponent": it's for the whole equation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Annihilator Method](http://www.utdallas.edu/dept/abp/PDF_Files/DE_Folder/Annihilator_Method.pdf), we have the following points for 1. :

- When we have the term $D^3$ in the ODE so the terms $$c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2$$ will appear in $y(x)$.
- When we have the term $D+5$ in the ODE so the terms $$c_4\exp(-5x)$$ will appear in $y(x)$.
- When we have the term $(D+3)^2$ in the ODE so the terms $$c_5\exp(-3x)+c_6x\exp(-3x)$$ will appear in $y(x)$.
- When we have the term $D^2+16$ in the ODE so the terms $$c_7\sin(4x)+c_8\cos(4x)$$ will appear in $y(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

1) If we set
$$
P_1=D^3,\quad P_2=D+5,\quad P_3=(D+3)^2,\quad P_4=D^2+16,
$$
then $P_iP_j=P_jP_i$ for every $i,j$. Therefore, the general solution $y$ of 
$$
D^3(D+5)(D+3)^2(D^2+16)y=P_1P_2P_3P_4y=0
$$
is given by
$$
y=\mu_1\phi_1+\mu_2\phi_2+\mu_3\phi_3+\mu_4\phi_4,
$$ 
where $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3$ and $\mu_4$ are real constants and 
$$
P_1\phi_1=0,\quad P_2\phi_2=0,\quad P_3\phi_3=0,\quad P_4\phi_4=0.
$$
It is obvious that
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_1(x)&=&a_0+a_1x+a_1x^2,\quad \phi_2(x)=be^{-5x},\\ 
\phi_3(x)&=&(c_0+c_1x)e^{-3x},\quad \phi_4(x)=d_1\cos4x+d_2\sin4x.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$
y=C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2+C_3e^{-3x}+C_4e^{-5x}+C_5\cos4x+C_6\sin4x.
$$
2) Since 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2e^y+y\cos y)=2xe^y=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2xe^y),
$$
it follows that there exists a function $(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2xe^y,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=x^2e^y+y\cos y.
$$
From the identity
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2xe^y
$$
we deduce that
$$
f(x,y)=x^2e^y+g(y).
$$
Since
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=x^2e^y+g'(y)=x^2e^y+y\cos y,
$$
it follows that
$$
g'(y)=y\cos y.
$$
Therefore
$$
g(y)=\int y\cos y\,dy=\int y(\sin y)'\,dy=y\sin y-\int\sin y\,dy=y\sin y+\cos y+C.
$$
Since
$$
2xe^ydx+(x^2e^y+y\cos y)dy=0 \iff df(x,y)=0 \iff f(x,y)=C',
$$
where $C'$ is a real constant. It follows that the general solution of
$$
2xe^ydx+(x^2e^y+y\cos ydy)=0
$$
is the family of curves given by
$$
x^2e^y+y\sin y+\cos y=c,
$$
where $c$ is real constant.